# SearchView imeOptions and onQueryTextSubmit support

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, searchview

I'm currently using [ActionBarSherlock 4.2](http://www.actionbarsherlock.com) and it's [SearchView](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/library/src/com/actionbarsherlock/widget/SearchView.java) widget in my app.

I wanted to make it submit query even though it's empty. I tried to set imeOptions and OnKeyListener but both were ignored without a reason.

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateOptionsMenu");
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.interactive_map, menu);
    mSearchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();

    mSearchView.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO);
    mSearchView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            Log.d(TAG, "keyCode: " + keyCode); 
            Log.d(TAG, "Action: " + event.getAction());
            if(keyCode == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH){
                onQueryTextSubmit(""+mSearchView.getQuery());
            }

            return false;
        }
    });


    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

onKey's never get triggered as both Logcat entries never appear in Logcat window. Not sure if this being inside SherlockFragment is the problem.

Nothing special's done to the menu item as well.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:title="@string/app_name"
          android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
          android:showAsAction="always"
          android:actionViewClass="com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

Is there a way to get around this? Or is there simpler way to enable submitting when query is empty? It doesn't seems to support any configuration in the source code though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I switched to put SearchView via ActionMode instead. I'll accept this as an answer for now until someone has a better solution for this question.

```
private void showActionMode(){
    MainActivity a = (MainActivity)getActivity();
    a.startActionMode(new SearchActionMode());
}

private class SearchActionMode implements ActionMode.Callback{

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateActionMode creating inflater");
        MenuInflater inflater = new MenuInflater(getActivity());
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateActionMode inflating");
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.interactive_map, menu);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateActionMode finding SearchView");
        mSearchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();

        Log.d(TAG, "mSearchView: " + mSearchView);
        setupSearchView();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPrepareActionMode");
        //TODO add searchView once working
        mSearchView.requestFocus(); 
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onActionItemClicked");
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroyActionMode");
        closeTopTray();
        closeListView();
    }

}


private void setupSearchView() {

    mSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    mSearchView.setId(ID_SEARCH_VIEW);
    mSearchView.setOnSearchClickListener(this);
    mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    mSearchView.setOnCloseListener(this);
    mSearchView.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH);

    // To automatically display keyboard when display SearchView
    mSearchView.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            Log.d(TAG, "mSearchView focus changed: " + hasFocus);
            if (hasFocus) {
                showInputMethod(v.findFocus());
            }
        }
    });

    mSearchView.setQueryHint("Type keyword");
    mSearchView.setQuery((TextUtils.isEmpty(searchQuery)? "": searchQuery), false);
}
```

Comment: here is another solution. works with less code. http://stackoverflow.com/a/32023365/1987045

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the problem lies onSubmitQuery() in SearchView.java

```
private void onSubmitQuery() {
    CharSequence query = mQueryTextView.getText();
    if (query != null && TextUtils.getTrimmedLength(query) > 0) {
```

Empty query's are not supported so I had to download and use [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) and then modify this method.

This is how my onSubmitQuery() looks like now

```
private void onSubmitQuery() {
     CharSequence query = mQueryTextView.getText();
     if (query == null) {query = "";}
     if (mOnQueryChangeListener == null
             || !mOnQueryChangeListener.onQueryTextSubmit(query.toString())) {
         if (mSearchable != null) {
             launchQuerySearch(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_UNKNOWN, null, query.toString());
             setImeVisibility(false);
         }
         dismissSuggestions();
     }
 }
```

Hope this helps.