# search with Sherlock ActionBar SearchView setOnKeyListener

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, searchview

I am trying the ActionBarSherlock SearchView. 
unfortunately the

```
       public boolean onKey(View arg0, int arg1, KeyEvent event)
```

is not fired.
Do you know the reason?
I see from this post
[SearchView imeOptions and onQueryTextSubmit support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13527181/searchview-imeoptions-and-onquerytextsubmit-support)
that a user solved the problem in another way. Maybe I should do the same?

Thanks

Here is my code:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    //Used to put dark icons on light action bar
    boolean isLight = SampleList.THEME == R.style.Theme_Sherlock_Light;

    //Create the search view
   final SearchView searchView = new SearchView(getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext());
    searchView.setQueryHint("Search for countriesâ€¦");

    System.out.println("searchView.getQuery()"+searchView.getQuery());

    searchView.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener()
    {
    /**
      * This listens for the user to press the enter button on
      * the keyboard and then hides the virtual keyboard
      */
           @Override
        public boolean onKey(View arg0, int arg1, KeyEvent event) {
        // If the event is a key-down event on the "enter" button

               System.out.println("--->"+searchView.getQuery());
        if ( (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN ) &&
        (arg1 == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) )
        {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)     SearchViews.this.getSystemService(SearchViews.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(searchView.getWindowToken(), 0);
        return true;
        }
        return false;
        }



    } );

    menu.add("Search")
        .setIcon(isLight ? R.drawable.ic_search_inverse : R.drawable.abs__ic_search)
        .setActionView(searchView)
        .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW);

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Avoid doing anything like this. Use **SearchView.OnQueryTextListener**

```
final SearchView searchView = new SearchView(getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext());
searchView.setQueryHint("Search for countries..");
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        return false;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        if (query.length() != 0) {
            System.out.println("--->" + query);
            // handle search here
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Always read [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html)

Comment: good answer, this method is the good one. But look at my question i'm currently having some issues with this OnQueryTextListener