# Android SearchView onclick

Tags: android, onclick, searchview

I have a searchView which looks like this:

```
private void setupSearchView() {
    mSearchView = (SearchView) getActivity().findViewById(
            R.id.search_view_neue);
    setSearchViewBackground();
    mSearchView.setOnClickListener(this);
    mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
}




    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    searchcounter = searchcounter + 1;

    setSearchViewBackground();
    ArrayList<WissensdokumenteRecord> documents = settingListContent(new ArrayList<WissensdokumenteRecord>());

    setListAdapter(new NeueWissensdokumentItemAdapter(
            inflater.getContext(), R.layout.row_example, documents));
    InputMethodManager im = (InputMethodManager) getActivity()
            .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    im.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getActivity().getCurrentFocus()
            .getWindowToken(), 0);

    return false;
}




<SearchView
    android:id="@+id/search_view_neue"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border_searchview"
    android:maxWidth="540dp"
    android:queryHint="Neue Dokumente suchen" >
</SearchView>
```

So, the behaviour of the search view is, that the keyboard opens by clicking the search button.  Now I can search for something. Is it possible to do a search by clicking anywhere in the searchview? Does anyone has an example for me?

Comment: There is good answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14602807/android-how-to-detect-click-on-custom-searchview-element

Answer (score 17):

I managed to do this in the following way:

Setup the search view on click listener

```
mSearchView.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Catch the onClick event:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.searchView:
            mSearchView.onActionViewExpanded();
            break;
    }
}
```

In this way the keyboard and search are activated if you click antwhere on the search bar.

Answer (score 8):

This will do exactly what you're trying to achieve.
`setIconified(false)` will keep the cross icon at this end of the SearchView so that the user can still cancel the same way as if the magnifying glass was clicked.

```
searchView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        searchView.setIconified(false);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 7):

I must suggest to use `setOnSearchClickListener` listner to detect `SearchView` click as According to Android [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html#setOnSearchClickListener(android.view.View.OnClickListener)) :

> setOnSearchClickListener
>
> void setOnSearchClickListener (View.OnClickListener listener)
>
> Sets a listener to inform when the search button is pressed.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.orders_menu, menu);
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);

    if (searchView != null) {
        searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
        searchView.setOnSearchClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
              //perform your click operation here 
            }
        });
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you need to to set OnClickListener on it.
By clicking on a SearchView you will update text cursor. To perform search you have a keyboard IME action. If clicking on it would perform search it would be impossible to change cursor etc. It is the generally wrong behaviour to make something else than focus / update cursor in text fields.

As far as I remember - you don't need to hide keyboard in OnQueryTextListener. It should hite automatically. Handle your search in OnQueryTextSubmit

[search with Sherlock ActionBar SearchView setOnKeyListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14772464/search-with-sherlock-actionbar-searchview-setonkeylistener/14772811#14772811)

Answer (score 0):

A search widget that intercepts all touches on its children and does a callback on touch down:

```
class InterceptTouchSearchView(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : SearchView(context, attrs) {

  var onActionDownIntercepted: (() -> (Unit))? = null

  override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
    return true
  }

  @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
  override fun onTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
    if (ev?.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
      onActionDownIntercepted?.invoke()
    }
    return false
  }
}
```

Usage: `search_view.onActionDownIntercepted = { onSearchFieldClicked() }`

Answer (score 0):

If you set `android:iconifiedByDefault="false"` and `setOnSearchClickListener` is not efftected.
You can try

```kotlin
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(QueryTextListener(searchView))

class QueryTextListener(private val searchView: SearchView) : OnQueryTextListener {
    override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
        // do something
        searchView.clearFocus()
        return true
    }

    override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
        return true
    }
}
```