# Hide the keyboard after a user finishes a query on a SearchView

Tags: java, android, searchview

Hi I am having trouble figuring out how to hide the Android Virtual Keyboard after a search query with a search view. I want the keyboard to disappear when the user presses the return key (ideally when they tap anywhere outside the keyboard but I will settle for the return key for now). I have it working for a query using onQueryTextSubmit working:

```
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
        //Search stuff...
        searchView.clearFocus();
        return true;
    }
```

however I'd like it to also work if the query is an empty string. The problem is onQueryTextSubmit is not fired if it is an empty string: [Android SearchView.OnQueryTextListener OnQueryTextSubmit not fired on empty query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13576283/android-searchview-onquerytextlistener-onquerytextsubmit-not-fired-on-empty-quer)

I'd also not like to use ActionBarSherlock so this solution will not do: [Android SearchView empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15992882/android-searchview-empty-string)

I just want to hide the keyboard after a user searches :( it seems like such a simple problem but is giving me a headache. Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: Having the same problem. Any progress?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the compatibility library:

```
MenuItemCompat.collapseActionView(searchItem);//searchItem is an instance of MenuItem
```

If you are not using the compatibility library:

```
searchItem.collapseActionView();
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking to know when to implement these (specifically when the search query is empty).

Comment: Ok I see what you are trying to do. I will edit my answer. Are you using the compatibility library? If not what version of Android are you targeting?

Answer (score 1):

Use InputMethodManager:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

for empty query string solution:
[Android SearchView.OnQueryTextListener OnQueryTextSubmit not fired on empty query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13576283/android-searchview-onquerytextlistener-onquerytextsubmit-not-fired-on-empty-quer)

Comment: Thank you but I am not sure if this what I am looking for. As stated above, I have the keyboard hiding on return presses EXCEPT for on empty strings. I already have looked at that link as well as referenced in my original question.

Comment: @John, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13527181/searchview-imeoptions-and-onquerytextsubmit-support

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
searchView.setQuery("", false);
searchView.setIconified(true);
```

Answer (score -1):

public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
        //Search stuff...

```
    searchView.setIconified();
    searchView.clearFocus();
    searchView.onActionViewCollapsed();
    return true;
}
```